# Manually set bluetooth server port in Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, port

I have a working Bluetooth server running (Android app). I would like to set a specific Bluetooth port for it to listen to. The reason for that is that for the client to connect, it takes about 10-15 seconds because it needs to first discover the server (i do a scan ).

the code to create the server is the following:

```
            BluetoothAdapter adapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
            UUID my_uuid = UUID.fromString("12345678-f6ff-4f6f-1f1f-f8f8f8fffff8");
            try {
                BluetoothServerSocket serverSocket = adapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord("myBluetoothServer", my_uuid);

                sock1 = serverSocket.accept();
                i_s = sock1.getInputStream();
                o_s = new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
                new Thread(writter).start();
     ...
```

Question: how to specify a fixed port number for the server?

I have been looking here, of course, but it is not easy to find,:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothSocket?hl=ur

I am looking for something like serverSocket.setPort(myPortNumber) (pseudo - code)

Answer (score 0):

The concept of port does not exist for Bluetooth Sockets since they are not regular TCP/IP sockets. They are just abstracted to behave like one.

As you figured out from your code, what you specify is a UUID which is a service identifier. The process to connect to a Bluetooth server goes like this:

1. Bluetooth Device scan: You can't skip this part, since you need a valid BluetoothDevice object
2. Service Discovery for a discovered Device: This is the part where you "check" if that Bluetooth Device is running the service that you are looking for (Your service UUID) So you shouldn't skip this part either, unless you want to connect to all surrounding Bluetooth devices.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Maybe i wasn't clear. The thing is since the devices are paired i can in fact directly connect the client to server if i know the port (i manually tested it), and the assumption is that i know the BLE MAC address of the server. do you see the idea?

Comment: As i stated before, there are no such things as ports for Bluetooth Servers. If you already have the relevant Bluetooth device you want to connect to, then all you need to do is: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothSocket.html?hl=ur#connect() as mentioned in the documentation that you linked.

Comment: Also, you should be aware that MAC addresses are randomized for Bluetooth Devices starting from API 23 so you should not rely on that.

Comment: i hear what you say, yet there is something called a "port" when you display all the discoreverd services e.g.:

Comment: {'description': '',
  'handle': 65549,
  'host': '00:00:00:00:00:00',
  'name': b'OBEX Object Push\x00',
  'port': 12,
  'profiles': [(b'1105', 256)],
  'protocol': 'RFCOMM',
  'provider': None,

Comment: (i just put 00s everywhere for my MAC otherwise rest is same) -> port 12!

Comment: why would you say that there is not port since it is called that way there ?